# Compare DateTime without year

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to get an alert when a Customer has their birthday within the next 7 days.

I've tried it with this code:

```
public bool IsBirthdayImminent
{
    get { return DateOfBirth != null && DateOfBirth.Value.Date >= DateTime.Today.Date.AddDays(-7); }
}
```

Of course this doesn't work, as the Date is stored with its year (say 05/21/1980) and it also compares the year. So this query will never be `true` - well, not if you're born within the next seven days though.

How can I modify this query to ignore the year?

**Edit:**

Alright, the query itself is not a problem at all. My primary point is the handling of leap years and situations around December <-> January.

Comment: Try : DateOfBirth.Value.Date >= DateTime.Today.Date.AddYears(DateOfBirth.Value.Date.Year - DateTime.Today.Date.Year).AddDays(-7)

Comment: Normalize both dates: make a copy of the DOB value and set the year to be the same as the current year. Now you'll be comparing apples to apples.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Might that not have issues with leap years?  If, for example, one of the dates is Feb 29th 1996 and you try to set it to Feb 29th 2013 you may not get the desired result.  Same same for any other differences between dates over the years.

Comment: @SeToY, have you checked mine ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would suggest using the following code. This includes cases around December - January and February, 29th. Though you might want to take a look and correct February 28th to be included or excluded within the given `days`.

```
    BirthdayImminent(new DateTime(1980, 1, 1), new DateTime(2012, 1, 2), 7); // false
    BirthdayImminent(new DateTime(1980, 1, 1), new DateTime(2012, 12, 28), 7); // true
    BirthdayImminent(new DateTime(1980, 2, 28), new DateTime(2012, 2, 21), 7); // true

    private static bool BirthdayImminent(DateTime birthDate, DateTime referenceDate, int days)
    {
        DateTime birthdayThisYear = birthDate.AddYears(referenceDate.Year - birthDate.Year);

        if (birthdayThisYear < referenceDate)
            birthdayThisYear = birthdayThisYear.AddYears(1);

        bool birthdayImminent = (birthdayThisYear - referenceDate).TotalDays <= days;

        return birthdayImminent;
    }
```

Also keep the edge case in mind [Guvante](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16947949/compare-datetime-without-year#comment-24472920) posted in the comments below.

Comment: +1 for `AddYears` instead of trying to hack together a constructor. Technically for `days >= 60` your handling of leap birthdays is off by one. Making both `AddYears` function off the `birthDate` would fix that edge condition (`2/29/2012.AddYears(3).AddYears(1) == 2/28/2016`). However given the requirements I would say your method is best, since the correction adds non obviously reasoned redundancy.

Comment: @Guvante That doesn't apply to all days >= 60, just leap years when the current date is also a leap year but before the 28th.  It is off by one day under those conditions though.  This is why I so rarely answer DateTime questions.  They're super messy.

Comment: @Servy: Do you think correcting the amount of leap days between `birthdayThisYear` (after last assignment) and `birthDate` will be sufficient?

Comment: @Caramiriel Actually, looking back on it, it's never an issue.  As Guv showed, if you call addyears twice (say adding 3 years and then add one more year later) it won't always be the same as just adding 4 years in one go.  However, the only time you ever add years are when the birthday is earlier in the year than the current date.  The only way there would ever be a problem is if the birthday was on a leap year and the current date is 8 days prior, and in that case it is never calling `AddYears` twice, so it can't break.

Comment: @Servy: I was only talking about an incredibly rare condition, one of those "once in a lifetime" things, where the next year is a leap year, you are late enough in the year to care about next year, they are a leap baby, and they would exactly missing the timespan (aka it covers 2/28 but not 2/29). As I said before, not a meaningful omission, just something I noticed. It would never happen for `days == 7` only for `days >= 60` (and all the previous conditions).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
DateTime birthDate = new DateTime(2012, 12, 2);

DateTime birthdayThisYear;
if (birthDate.Month == 2 && birthDate.Day == 29 && DateTime.IsLeapYear(DateTime.Now.Year))
    birthdayThisYear = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 2, 28);
else
    birthdayThisYear = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, birthDate.Month, birthDate.Day);

bool birthdayImminent = birthdayThisYear > DateTime.Now && (birthdayThisYear - DateTime.Now).TotalDays <= 7;
```

As a getter:

```
public bool IsBirthdayImminent
{
    get 
    { 
        if (DateOfBirth == null) 
            return false;
        else
        {
            DateTime birthdayThisYear;
            if (birthDate.Month == 2 && birthDate.Day == 29 && DateTime.IsLeapYear(DateTime.Now.Year))
                birthdayThisYear = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 2, 28);
            else
                birthdayThisYear = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, birthDate.Month, birthDate.Day);

            return birthdayThisYear > DateTime.Now && (birthdayThisYear - DateTime.Now).TotalDays <= 7;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 If someone is born on Feb 29th this will throw an exception most years you call it.

Comment: @SeToY - Looks good. It is also worth adding a check to make sure the bithdate is in the future, i.e. '&& birthdayThisYear > DateTime.Now'

Comment: @Servy - Good spot, it would require a check for birthdays where month is 'Feb' and Day is '29th', where the OP needs to decide how to handle the -1 day.

Comment: It should be where the current year is *not* a leap year.  Also, I think there are some other leap days, besides just feb 28, in certain cultures at certain times, so I'm not entirely sure this will work in all cases.

Comment: The [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16948192/1159478) is much clearer and doesn't have this potential for breaking.

Comment: @Servy - Yeap, the other answer is better, +1

Comment: It also doesn't work for the December-January span.  Birthday in January but the current date is at the end of December.

Answer (score 0):

Set the birtdate's year explicitly to `DateTime.Today.Year`, and it will compare just fine.

Comment: Be aware of cases around December-January though.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public bool IsBirthdayImminent
{
    get { return DateOfBirth != null && DateOfBirth.Value.Date.AddYear(DateTime.Now.Year -DateOfBirth.Value.Year) >= DateTime.Today.Date.AddDays(-7); }
}
```

Comment: This will return true if the birthday was either in the last 7 days or is any time between now and the end of the year.

Comment: that's not very elegant , while there are better solutions ! and I agree with @Jim